# Under new management - how should I deal with my new boss?

Tags: management

We work in a small environment, (2 offices, no more than 10 employees). Our old boss was recently promoted, and a new guy has been brought in to replace him.

I am asking on behalf of my female coworker. Her position is the Document Controller, and she has quite a bit of responsibility in the workplace; talking to clients in regards to job requirements, keeping them informed of job progress, transmittals, and (of course) document management.

Under the old boss, she often argued (constructively - there wasn't any hatred between them) with him, discussing different options about workflow etc. He didn't always agree with her, and would often go his own way anyway, but he always listened to her opinions. He was also a very strong believer in the "team dynamic"; where she played the "discipline" role, making sure that everyone else had done their jobs right, making sure that everything flowed as it should, following the workflows etc.

Now, under the new boss, she seems to be little more than the errand girl. The new boss often asks her to do things, and she would voice her opinion (as she did with our old boss), and he would go over her head (that is, ask someone else - his manager, or someone else in charge of a job) to get confirmation. He would ask her to do things, and expect it to be done, no please's or thankyou's, regardless of her concerns. She has also had some sensitive health issues, and was forced to confront him about it, regardless of the fact that those issues were very private, just so that she could avoid getting herself into situations that would put her at further risk.

She has recently voiced her opinion (rather unexpectedly) to me about wanting to quit because of it, even though she says that she loves her job.

As she is the only female employee that he deals with on a regular basis, we aren't entirely sure if this is just his lack of understanding about her responsibilities, or if there are other issues.

How should we approach this, in an attempt to make everyone understand the situation?

Comment: Do you still have any access to your former manager?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes.

Comment: That might be a good person to ask for advice.

Comment: So your coworker vents to you and you vent here on her behalf? And you feel the need to insert vague hints at discrimination with zero basis for them? A new manager came in and he apparently sees this "Document Controller" as more of an administrative role. That could be entirely reasonable and you don't even say what you want to do about it (and hint: this isn't any of your business). And I can't even wrap my head around the fact that she had to volunteer medical info to avoid possible issues at work, is the new manager supposed to be psychic then? **Vote to close.**

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, if old boss is now in the direct chain above new boss the contact is less useful

Comment: @Lilienthal firstly; yes, there are a few assumptions here, and yes I can see how you might feel I'm hinting at things, but from what we have personally experienced, certain aspects of his behaviour is exclusive to her. I'm not enforcing the belief that this is the case; There isn't enough evidence, which is what I was attempting to clarify. Secondly, yes her role is administrative, but seeing as her responsibilities have massively changed, she is feeling like her role/responsibility in the workplace is not being valued.

Comment: And finally, I'm just trying to help a colleague with their problems. I understand that I personally should not be dealing with this myself - it is not my place. I'm just trying to find some advice for my colleague, not solve their problems for them.

Comment: @Patricia yeah, as a few other users have suggested, this is the case. While there might be a bit of a personal relationship with our old boss, he is still in a higher position, so I don't think it's wise to go straight to him.

Comment: @Ben The problem is that you can't really tell us what your coworker's goals are and that's a crucial aspect for questions on this site. We don't do generic "in your situation I would do X" because that's not useful to others and it's impossible to judge answers like that. As I said this appears to be more about venting frustration than about solving a problem. Even if you rephrase it to "How can coworker convince her boss to redefine her role?" that'd be tricky to answer since we have no clue as to your company's structure and whether it even makes sense to do so.

Comment: The fact that her previous boss apparently saw her role differently and valued her input more is potentially a credit to him (depending on whether her input was in fact valuable and it made sense for the way he ran his team) but not by itself sufficient reason for new management to keep doing so if they see things differently. The only real solution to that is finding a new job that fits her interests.

Answer (score 9):

> How should we approach this?

*First off, you should stay out of it, it's not your business. Talk with your friend, but don't inject yourself into the issue. There's no "we" here.*

She should have a discussion with her new boss. She should ask her boss to explain what he needs out of her in her role. She could explain in detail what she used to do, hoping that the new boss just didn't realize what she was capable of. But in the end, her boss will decide what her role is to be.

And if that doesn't fit with what she wants to do, she should find a new job first before quitting.

With a new boss, often there comes new expectations, and shifting roles - particularly in a small office. Nobody is guaranteed that what they used to do will be what they are expected to do forever.

If the new environment no longer fits her needs, then she needs to decide if she wants to adjust to the new role or not. And if not, she may need to move on to a new job.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I do realize that it is not my place to be involving myself in this directly, all I am trying to do is find some advice for how my colleague should handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you think about quitting give it 90 days.

- In the first 30 cool off and comply
- For the second 30 decide what you can live with and communicate that to
  your boss
  Don't present it as a demand - but this is what I would like
  Polish your resume and send out feelers
- For the last 30 decide if your boss is willing to comply

Answer (score 0):

It seems you firmly believe of the value she add to the team. Your implicit belief in treating everyone fairly and well speaks highly of you. Continue doing what you have been doing and show the rest of your team **you believe** in fairness, and an environment of open communication. **Be the change you want to see**.

The boss may not seem to believe in her abilities and also seems to have a different management style. As you are underneath him, your options are limited. In the long term, a manager that does not respect or listen to the team is ultimately bound to fail.

Try to have a private conversation with this coworker and simply reflect back what she says:

1. That she wants to quit due to lack of open communication
2. She feels she is not as respected / treated well as before.
3. You still believe in her ability and her importance to the team
4. Talk to her new manager about what she sees and how the changes are affecting her.

**Even if others are behaving less than desired, you can still hold yourself to higher standards.**